# incorrect estimate_normals with open3d?

Tags: python, matlab, point-clouds

I am trying to calculate the normals of a point cloud formed by three planes each aligned with an axis.
In matlab the function pcnormals gives me a coherent result, while when I try to do the same with estimate_normals of open3d the result is incorrect.
The code is here:

```
import numpy as np
from open3d import *
pcd = read_point_cloud("D:\Artificial.txt",format = 'xyz')
estimate_normals(pcd, search_param =  KDTreeSearchParamKNN(knn = 25))
x = np.concatenate((np.asarray(pcd.points),np.asarray(pcd.normals)),axis=1)
np.savetxt("D:\ArtificialN_python.txt",x,delimiter=',')
```

I also have tried with differen knn value and search_param, but the result is similar.

I enclose the images of the coloured clouds according to the third component of the normal one (red-horizontal and green-inclined) calculated with matlab and python.

**matlab result:**

[image]

**python result:**

[image]

Anybody know what that might be due to?